# Django collectstatic command isn't removing deleted files

Tags: django, collectstatic

I've discovered that the collectstatic command isn't removing the files I deleted in the static folder, I'm using the `grunt-django-compressor` plugin which generates new compressed js and css files everytime there are changes in the uncompressed ones to prevent cache problems, it removes the old files from the repository and creates new ones.

When I run the command in production it copies the new files correctly but I think it should delete the old ones, this is not happening.

Who had the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried the `-c` option?

Comment: No, I didn't, I'm going to try it

Comment: -c option seems to DELETE ALL FILES not just the missing once.